Microsoft.Data.SqlClient data layer equivalent
In Microsoft.Data.SqlClient which is the equivalent of System.Data.SqlClient data layer?
I'm rewriting an old procedure from a fired collaborator and now I have that problem...
It's a simple question I know... but I found nothing on the web...
Thanks...

What is System.Data.SqlClient DataLayer? Also what does that have to do with re-writing a procedure? Are you talking about a SQL stored procedure?

For the most part, any code written for System.Data.SqlClient should work as is with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient with just a change of imported namespace. The latter adds functionality but doesn't take much, if anything, away. If this doesn't answer your question then your question is too vague and needs to be rewritten for clarity.

This doesn't sound like a stable working environment. I'd advise learning about ADO.NET from books and tutorials, not just trying to get the old code working. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, System.Data.SqlClient, NpgSql (for PostgreSQL), MySqlConnector are just database drivers. The actual data access library is ADO.NET. The classes and techniques are the same, no matter the driver. There are a lot of books, courses, tutorials and videos on ADO.NET going back all the way to 2002.

If you are asking about Microsoft.Data.SqlClient vs System.Data.SqlClient, then yes: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient should be preferred and is where the ongoing development is more focused; however, System.Data.SqlClient remains available and usable even on current .NET via this NuGet package. In reality: please use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient unless you have a very good reason.
If you're specifically asking about a technology / API called "DataLayer" (rather than the vague data layer concept): you're going to have to be more specific. AFAIK, that's not a thing.

Something tells me the real problem isn't the drivers, but the company that makes a beginner maintain legacy ADO.NET code, probably because there's nobody else left ...
